# Angular DragDrop - how to reorder items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

**THE SITUATION:**

I have an app that make use of [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop) to move items between three separate list.

The drag and drop is working fine. But i also need to reorder the items inside the same list.

I see in the documentation that is possible to retrive the index also on the onDrop, but i don't know how.
If i will be able to retrive the index - that is the position where the item is left in the new array - then i would be able to make the reordering

**THE CODE:**

```
        <ul class="thumbnails">
          <li class="span3" style='margin-left:10px;'>
            <div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" ng-model='list1' data-jqyoui-options="optionsList1" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">
              <div class="caption">
                <div class="btn btn-info btn-draggable" ng-repeat="item in list1" ng-show="item.title" data-drag="{{item.drag}}" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="list1" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}}, animate:true, onStart:'set_item_id({board_item_id: item.item_id}, {index: $index})'}">{{item.title}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="span3" style='margin-left:10px;'>
            <div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" ng-model='list2' data-jqyoui-options="{accept:'.btn-draggable:not([ng-model=list2])'}"  jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">
              <div class="caption">
                <div class="btn btn-info btn-draggable" ng-repeat="item in list2" ng-show="item.title" data-drag="{{item.drag}}" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="list2" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true, onStart:'set_item_id({board_item_id: item.item_id}, {index: $index})'}">{{item.title}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="span3" style='margin-left:10px;'>
            <div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" ng-model='list3' data-jqyoui-options="{accept:'.btn-draggable:not([ng-model=list3])'}"  jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">
              <div class="caption">
                <div class="btn btn-info btn-draggable" ng-repeat="item in list3" ng-show="item.title" data-drag="{{item.drag}}" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="list3" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true, onStart:'set_item_id({board_item_id: item.item_id}, {index: $index})'}">{{item.title}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
```

**THE PLUNKER:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/YiAylkMCX9TAGyyhwO1m?p=preview

**THE QUESTION:**

How can re-order items inside a list, using angular-dragdrop?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just use orderBy by the id in ng-repeat. Something like this `ng-repeat="item in list2 | orderBy:'item_id'"`

Comment: thank you for reply! Let's say i want to order the items according to a field 'item_order'. The main point is that if i drop the item in the position 2 of the new array - i want to take the new $index and assign as the new posiiton. The only missing thing is how to take the new $index position

Comment: Can you explain with an example? I assumed that if I drag Item2 of list1 below Item 6 of list2 then the items should be sorted like this Item2, item5 and Item6 for list2. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: To make it simple i would like to reorder items also inside the same list. Bring one from the bottom to top, grab the index and save as new position.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add additional directives in order to make sure the sorting option is enabled in the list.

```
data-drop="true" jqyoui-droppable="{index: {{$index}}}"
```

Here is the working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/N0z6ud?p=preview