# Angular dragdrop css class on drag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-ui

I am using [Angular dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop) in my app.

I need to change the color of the borders of the drop area when drag an item hover them.

There is a css class i can use for this purpose?
If not, how can i do that?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `onOver` and `onOut` Angular Droppable options and toggle the class for eg. `hover`

```
// HTML

<div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" ng-model="list2" 
    jqyoui-droppable="{onOver: 'onOver', onOut: 'onOut',  onDrop: 'onDrop'}" ng-bind="list2.title ? 'Dropped successfully..!' : 'Drop here...'"></div>

// JS

  $scope.onOver = function(e) {
   angular.element(e.target).addClass("hover");
  };
  $scope.onOut = function(e) {
    angular.element(e.target).removeClass("hover");
  };
  $scope.onDrop = function(e) {
    angular.element(e.target).removeClass("hover").addClass("done");
  };
```

[Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/w6l5kNs9NfAOxLHEASd1?p=preview)

Comment: Updated the answer. Use onDrop for removing class that was added on hover. [Check this](http://plnkr.co/edit/w6l5kNs9NfAOxLHEASd1?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! You seems very acknowledge with angular drag drop! Can you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295346/angular-dragdrop-css-class-on-drag

Nobody was able to answer yet..

Comment: You have linked to this post again.

Comment: sorry :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799766/angular-dragdrop-how-to-reorder-items